# Oracle logic to roll the value same level

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing issue is solving on oracle logic

I have below requirement, I have one table with Some Numbers and Corresponding ID. I want to write logic where few rows are rolled same No. Please let me know what is best way to solve this. I have used left outer join on same table but its giving me cross join.

```
NO  ID
1   A
1   B
1   C
2   A
2   B
2   C

NO  ID  RoID
1   A   C
1   B   
2   A   C
2   B
```

Comment: Can you show the code which you have written and the required output?

Comment: And can you explain exactly what you mean by " I want to write logic where few rows are rolled same No."? My crystal ball is on the blink, sadly. Why is the 'C' value in the RoID column, and not A or B?

Comment: I am assuming you need the max id of each group no in roid.

Comment: NO ID Date
1 A 12/15/15
1 B 12/16/15
1 C 12/17/15
1 B 12/18/15
2 A 12/19/15
2 B 12/20/15
2 C 12/21/15
2 E 12/22/15


NO ID RoID Roll Date
1 A C 12/18/15
1 B  
2 A C 12/22/15
2 B  



SELECT v1.* ,v3.id as RoID, v2.rolling_date AS Roll Date FROM Table1 V1 
LEFt JOIN (SELECT ID,  Max(Date) AS Roll Date FROM Table1 
and ID IN ('C') group by ID  ) V2 ON  V1.COIL_ID = V2.COIL_ID 

LEFt JOIN (SELECT ID, Date FROM Table1  
and ID IN ('C')  ) V3 ON  V1.COIL_ID = V2.COIL_ID and V2.ROLLING_DATE = v3.RUN_DATE_READY_INT

 v1.ID IN ('A', 'B')

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your desired output using **Analytic functions**:

- **MAX() OVER()**
- **LAG() OVER()**

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT 1 NO, 'A' ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  3  SELECT 1 NO, 'B' ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT 1 NO, 'C' ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT 2 NO, 'A' ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  6  SELECT 2 NO, 'B' ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  7  SELECT 2 NO, 'C' ID FROM dual
  8  )
  9  -- end of sample_data mocking a real table
 10  SELECT no,
 11    id,
 12    lag(rn) over(PARTITION BY NO ORDER BY ID DESC) rn
 13  FROM
 14    ( SELECT t.*, MAX(ID) OVER(PARTITION BY NO ORDER BY ID DESC) rn FROM sample_data t
 15    )
 16  WHERE ID <> rn
 17  ORDER BY no,
 18    id;

        NO I R
---------- - -
         1 A C
         1 B
         2 A C
         2 B
```

Comment: NO ID Date
1 A 12/15/15
1 B 12/16/15
1 C 12/17/15
1 B 12/18/15
2 A 12/19/15
2 B 12/20/15
2 C 12/21/15
2 E 12/22/15


NO ID RoID Roll Date
1 A C 12/18/15
1 B  
2 A C 12/22/15
2 B  
My exact requirement is to have max of date for that particular No, and the Id to be  rolled over to corresponding No.

Comment: @Tushar Then use `MAX(date)` instead. You have a completely working example in my answer, tweak it the way you want.